# Next.js how to access static variables defined in page.js from layout.js

Tags: next.js

I'm using Next.js 13 app router.

How can I read the static variable defined in a page from the `layout.js`?

For example I have this title defined in `page.js`

```js
const Page = () => {
  return <div></div>;
};

Page.title = "Hello World";

export default Page;
```

and I want to render my header component from the `RootLayout`

```js
const RootLayout = ({ children, session }) => {
  // how can I access the title from page.js?
  // I want the layout to render differently if title is defined.
  const header = <h1>...</h1>;
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        {header}
        <main>{children}</main>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

It is similar to `Page.getLayout` in Next.js's [per-page layout example](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#per-page-layouts).

Do you have any idea how to do this in app route?

Comment: why do u need it?

Comment: @Yilmaz I want to render the title if it is defined in the page.

Comment: If it is defined in the page, you could render it in page.js? Why do u need to handle it from layout?

Comment: Rendering a header (and also the footer and side menu) to me is is part of the layout implementation. Hence, I want to render these common components in layout.js.

Imagine that the header is not just a simple div but a complex component. We have to duplicate the component in every page.